# UIlabel toggle bold

Tags: swift

I've managed to bold a UILabel using the following line:

`self.nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: self.nameLabel.font.pointSize)`

But I want to put this in an `if` statement that will make the UIlabel bold is it isn't bold, and unbold if it is.

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there are many other ways, I would suggest you to create a variable that stores whether the label is bold.

```
var isLabelBold = false
```

I would imagine that you have the bold/unbold label code put in a button's `IBAction` method. Now in that method, check whether `isLabelBold` is true:

```
if isLabelBold { // if label is bold
    // unbold it!
    self.nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: self.nameLabel.font.pointSize)

    isLabelBold = false
} else { // if label is not bold
    // bold it!
    self.nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: self.nameLabel.font.pointSize)
}
```